# Update state props without firing a dispatch() - React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a modal containing a button that fires a HTTP request, at which point the displayed html will change depending on a successful/error response from the server, where the response changes a state prop that is dealt with in the `mapStatesToProps` function.

The issue I have now is that I am wanting to reset the modal to its initial state pre-request when I close it.
I had previously done this by using local component state but have since updated the functionality to use the request mapped state props shown above.

I am curious if it possible to reset the state without firing a dispatch to a random URI?

**Component.jsx**

```
const mapStatesToProps = ({myState}) => ({
    response: myState.response,
    success: !!(myState.success),
    fail: !!(myState.fail)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    doReq: () => {
        dispatch(doMyRequest());
    }
});

class MyComponent extends Component {
    toggleModal = () => // modal toggle code

    render() {
        const {response, success, fail} = this.props;

        <div className="myModal">
            // Modal stuff here
            {!success && !fail && (
                <button onClick="() => toggleModal()">Close modal</button>
            )}
            {success && !fail && (
                <h1>Some success message</h1>
            )}
            {!success && fail && (
                <h1>Some fail message</h1>
            )}
        </div>
    }
}
```

**req-actions.js**

```
export const MY_REQUEST;
export const MY_REQUEST_SUCCESS;
export const MY_REQUEST_ERROR;

export const doMyRequest = () => ({
    type: MY_REQUEST,
    agent: agent.req.doRequest
})
```

**req-reducer.js**

```
import { deepEqual, deepClone } from '../McUtils';
import {
    MY_REQUEST,
    MY_REQUEST_ERROR,
    MY_REQUEST_SUCCESS
} from "../actions/req-actions";

export default (state = {}, action) => {
    let newState = deepClone(state);

    switch (action.type) {
        case MY_REQUEST:
            console.log('SENDING REQUEST');
            newState.response = null;
            newState.success = false;
            newState.fail = false;
            break;

        case MY_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            newState.response = action.payload;
            newState.success = true;
            newState.fail = false;
            break;

        case MY_REQUEST_ERROR:
            console.log('FAIL');
            newState.response = action.payload;
            newState.success = false;
            newState.fail = true;
            break;

        default:
            return state;
    }

    return newState;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. What is inside the modal, a form?

Comment: Instead of resetting the state when closing the modal without sending the request it would be better to keep a *draft* in a local state of the modal and only save it to the redux store when it has been successfully transmitted. Jut because an app uses redux there is no reason to store every single intermediate state in the store. If the modal contains a form that form state should probably be local to that form unless submitted. the modal should be an own component that gets mounted with the initial state from the the store when opened.

Comment: HIGHLY agree with @trixn. Redux is for application state, not ephemeral state. Here it is [defined by flutter](https://androidmonks.com/state-management-flutter/#Two_important_States_8211_Ephemeral_and_App_State) but it is 100% the exact same thing in react. I can't tell you how maddening it is to work on an application where devs have decided to put **everything** in redux instead of working with local state when applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use another action:

```js
case MY_REQUEST_RESET:
   return {} // only putting {} in here because this is what you have defined your initialState to be according to your reducer.
```

Personal preference is to clearly define your initial state like this.

```js
const initialState = {};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
       ... your existing handlers
       case MY_REQUEST_RESET:
          return initialState
    }
}
```

Wiring it up:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    doReq: () => {
        dispatch(doMyRequest()),
    },
    reset: () => {
        dispatch(resetMyRequest());
    }
});


// types
const MY_REQUEST_RESET = 'MY_REQUEST_RESET';

// action creator (may be referred to as "actions")
const resetMyRequest = () => ({ type: MY_REQUEST_RESET })
```

EDIT: While I'm here, this is really gross:

```js
let newState = deepClone(state);
```

and reeks of "I don't really know what I'm doing" and can lead to performance issues. You are deepCloning the state on **every action fired through redux**, even if the actions aren't one's this reducer is interested in.

If you are changing the state in the reducer, just change the part you are concerned with, don't change "all" of it.

e.g.

```js
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MY_REQUEST:
            console.log('SENDING REQUEST');
            return {
                success: false,
                fail: false,
                response: null
            }

        case MY_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            return {
                ...state, // this will contain "fail: false" already
                success: true,
                response: action.payload
            };

        case MY_REQUEST_ERROR:
            console.log('FAIL');
            return {
                ...state, // this will contain "success: false" already
                error: true,
                response: action.payload
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
```

Comment: With regards to the new Action, how would that wire up? Just thinking that if I'm creating a new dispatch: `dispatch(resetMyModal())`, it will go through to my action that will be in the format as seen in `req-actions.js` - Do I ignore the `agent` as I'm not sending an actual request? I have made the new case in the `reducer` section as you showed above. I'm just a bit confused about the `actions`

Comment: @physicsboy - add a wiring it up section to my answer.

Comment: Aha! Awesome! Thought it didn't work, but looks like I accidentally deleted another action XD
As for your (Trixn's) other suggestions, I know what you mean. Problems with picking up established codebases, aye? Will have a look into getting rid of deepClone at some point. Tech debt perhaps.